# read nested JSON with the .find() Method

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, transactions, nested-json

I'm stuck at reading out **nested JSON elements** that were saved in a **MongoDB**. I'm trying it with the following method:

```
blockChainModel.find({"transactions.user": "eltaieyo"}, null, {projection : { transactions: {user : 1}} }, (err, blocks) => {
            if (err) console.error("Cannot find the specified Blocks");
            console.log(blocks);
});
```

The JSON in the MongoDB, that I'm trying to read looks like this:
[JSON Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpRbN.png)

I want to read out the **"transactions"** section, and this is what the current method in my Code does:
[OUTPUT Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1dEa.png)

Maybe It is reading them out but my method doesn't give them out correctly?

Comment: The projection should be the 2nd param not the 3rd and also without the projection key `{ transactions: {user : 1}}` but first you should try without the projection. Check this playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/4DriEYeOzD-

Comment: @Molda I did that, thank you. It is returning all the data, expect for the nested data which is in the transactions array. That's the data that I need but it is giving it out like this:
transactions : [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]

Comment: The reason you see `[Object]` is just the way console.log works, i believe it only shows data 2 levels deep. To see the full data use either `console.log(JSON.stringify(blocks))` or `console.log(require('util').inspect(blocks))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about remove `projection` and try again to check if there is actually some data return ?

Comment: Data is being returned, the whole transaction is being returned but the necessary infos that are being stored in the "transactions" part is just put out like this:
transactions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]

Comment: Are you using `console.log()` to check the value, if so, you may need `JSON.stringify()` to reveal the [object]

Comment: Currently I'm using console.log() to give the transaction out. I'm just doing a blockChain prototype that will be used in a bigger project afterwards that's why i'm just using console.log() to check if everything works. If I do JSON.stringify(blocks), it does the same thing as before. Maybe I'm using it wrong

Comment: I think the data is fine, it actually return what you what in the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. It now gives the data out how i want it. Have a nice day ;)